# How to install "make" in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, centos, yum, apt

I'm trying to install "yum" or "apt-get" into my system "ubuntu centOS". I did download the binary files for these two programs from the internet using the command wget. but after decompressing the files using the command "tar -zxvf "filename" ,then configuring the file "./configuring", and then when I want to use the command "make" I get the following error "make: not found".

I have searched for a method to download the "make" command but all the methods I found on the net use either the command "yum" or "apt-get" and I don't have any of them.

Comment: You have this slightly wrong.
Make is not a program you need to download. it's a utility that comes integrated into nearly every distribution of linux.

Comment: Wait, what?  "ubuntu centOS"?  Those are two different flavors with their own (often radically different) ways of doing things.  It's almost certainly either one or the other, unless there's some freakish mashup of the two i haven't seen or heard of yet.  Either way, this is a question about installing software, and seems more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Just for future reference, there are a couple of major flavors of Linux.  I personally count 4: Debian (which includes Ubuntu), RedHat (which includes CentOS), Slackware (including SuSE), and Gentoo.  (Some would argue with Gentoo being "major", but IMO it's popular enough to earn a place, and it's definitely its own flavor.)  Most of the big distros are derived (indirectly or indirectly) from one of those main lines; the ones that aren't are typically specialized or indie-type stuff.  And the main flavors are different enough that you'll typically only derive from one of them.

Answer (score 66):

I have no idea what linux distribution "ubuntu centOS" is. Ubuntu and CentOS are two different distributions.

To answer the question in the header:
To install make in ubuntu you have to install build-essentials

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Although in Ubuntu, if you said "make" and `make` didn't exist (and you haven't modified the main bash profile, which someone who doesn't know how to install `make` almost certainly wouldn't know how to do), it'd almost certainly tell you what package to install to get it anyway...

Comment: ooh!, I thought centOS is an Ubuntu distribution, it seems I was wrong ^^'.  The problem is that I can't use the command "apt-get" nor the command "yum". It gives me an error "apt-get: not found". Thankx anyway.

Comment: @kadora: If it's CentOS, then yeah -- apt-get isn't the normal package manager.  You'd use yum, and probably `yum install make` would do it.

Comment: `apt-get -y install make` worked for me in a Dockerfile.