# make: pthread: Command not found

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

When I use "make" to crunch-3.6 in ubuntu, it happen error as below:

```
ubuntu@halflike:~/crunch-3.6$ sudo make
Building binary...
pthread -Wall -pedantic -std=c99   crunch.c -lm  -o crunch
make: pthread: Command not found
make: [crunch] Error 127 (ignored)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Something is wrong with that makefile `pthread` there should almost certainly be `-lpthread` and be an argument to a compiler. There is likely a compiler variable that is incorrectly unset `$(GCC)` or something. Also you *do not* want to run `make` as root most of the time.

Comment: I had solved the problem via "sudo apt-get install build-essential".See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934997/how-to-install-make-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because gcc was not installed on my computer, an `apt-get install gcc` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to install **GCC** to overcome this error...

type...   ***`apt-get install gcc`***

if you get any error during the installation of **GCC**...type following command...

type...   ***`apt-get update`***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is the same as the other answer and comments. Please refrain from adding answers which does not provide anything new.