# How to install Make on Windows?

Tags: windows, makefile

I'm running this code from Github:

```
# Modify Makefile.config according to your Caffe installation.
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
make -j8
# Make sure to include $CAFFE_ROOT/python to your PYTHONPATH.
make py
make test -j8
# (Optional)
make runtest -j8
```

And for the line:

```
make -j8
```

The output is:

> bash: make: command not found

Which is I think it is because `make` is not a valid command. What packages should I install and how? I tried looking for it on the internet about the error that I was getting but no luck.

I thought it was CMake that I'm missing and actually installed it. I got this in my `Program Files` folder:

[image]

But it still gives out the same error.

Comment: Have you checked ? [How to install “make” in ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11934997/2336650)

Comment: Oh sorry I don't have ubuntu.

Comment: And I opt to install it on Windows

Comment: Have you looked on the cmake website for installation instructions? https://cmake.org/install/

Comment: Note that CMake is a different piece of software. On some platforms it generates files for Make (but can't substitute for it either way). On Windows it is typically used to generate MSVS project files. https://cmake.org/overview/ Bottom line, it's not what you need.

Comment: I was confused because the dependencies in the Github page says cmake

Comment: There are multiple builds available but one of the most up-to-date that I know is here : https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i downloaded cmake but make is still not recognizable. So I downloaded make first then cmake afterwards then include it to my environmental variables. And I had to restart my laptop.