# Having trouble configuring VS code for c++ programs

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

I am having some troubles compiling c++ programs in VS code.  I followed  this answer: [How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code)

and my Makefile is

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall
.SUFFIXES = .cpp
objs:=$(wildcard *.cpp)
targets:=$(objs:.cpp= )

.PHONY:all
all: $(targets)
.cpp:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -std=c++11 -o $@ $<
```

I just want to compile this file which is opened in current window, say 1.cpp and this file does not have any external dependencies

When i try to compile my file (by pressing f8 as given in the answer i linked) i get the following error:

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am a beginner, and don't know much about Makefile , any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!
Edit:
I am using Windows subsystem for linux to compile my programs not mingw or cygwin.

**Edit:**
Now i can use make but i think something is wrong with my Makefile.   [image]

Comment: You may have to install make itself

Comment: @JETM  I have make installed (please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934997/how-to-install-make-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I am using windows subsystem for linux(bash) as terminal to compile my programs

Comment: Then the issue is that VSCode isn't looking for make in the right place. I don't know more than that, but maybe this clue can help you search.

Comment: @JETM when i type make in my terminal in vscode, it shows make: nothing to be found for 'all'  
so i think make command not found is not the case here.  
Can you check  if i am not making some other mistake here

Comment: @JETM have a look now, it seems to me that tasks.json is not correct but i can't figure out how to correct this

Comment: `make Makefile` is a very bad command, and may overwrite your makefile.  What you want is `make -f Makefile`

Comment: Also, your makefile is horribly wrong, and may overwrite source files, because you've designated them as generated files.  Make sure not to test this in your only copy of the code.

Comment: Bottom line, you don't have a Visual Studio Code problem.  Get things working when you run `make` at a command-line first, and only then worry about integration with Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a simple way:
args doesn't work some reason at least on my system.

So, change command (line 3 of tasks.json)

```
"command": "g++ -Wall -std=c++14 ${relativeFile};./a.out < input.txt
```

And now just one button and compile and run!